# change time locale for R

Tags: r, time, locale

Here is my `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong S.A.R..950 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong S.A.R..950   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong S.A.R..950
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                                          
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong S.A.R..950    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.14.0
```

I try to use `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")` to convert the output in date, but it gives me this error:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored
```

I wonder why and what can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For Windows:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
```

Comment: worked like a charm, whereas `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US")` didn't

Answer (score 15):

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
```

seems safer, works when "English" yields the "cannot be honored" warning.

Comment: "cannot be honored" on Ubuntu ~ your solution worked for me on 16.04

Answer (score 4):

Windows? If so the R Installation and Administration Manual says to look here for information about valid locale settings:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vccore98/html/_crt_language_and_country_strings.asp

It might help for you to say what your goals really are. Changing dates may not require changing your locale.