# How to get the day of week in english not in chinese?

Tags: r

In my console :

```
> format(as.Date("2010-01-01"), format="%A")
[1] "星期五"
```

How to get  the day of week in english not in chinese?
`"星期五"` is the chinese form of `friday`.

it is no use to set environment in my console.

```
> Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")
>  format(as.Date("2010-01-01"), format="%A")
[1] "星期五"
```

it  is no use to edit /etc/Rconsole, `Language=en`  .

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US")
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US") :
 OS reports request to set locale to "en_US" cannot be honored
>  format(as.Date("2010-01-01"), format="%A")
[1] "星期五"
```

my system is :xp+r -3.0.1.
i have edited  the file /etc/Rprofile.site  to add some lines:

```
.First <- function(){
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "English")
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "English")
Sys.setlocale("LC_MONETARY", "English")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")}
```

is there an other way to do ? to edit some file ,not to load the commands in /etc/Rprofile.site  when to  start R?

Comment: The answer here may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-the-language-of-errors-in-r/13575413#13575413

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the help file for `strptime`:

> Locale-specific conversions to and from character strings are used
>   where appropriate and available. This affects the names of the days
>   and months, the AM/PM indicator (if used) and the separators in
>   formats such as %x and %X (via the setting of the LC_TIME locale
>   category).

The minimal change would be to change `LC_TIME`:

In Windows the command appears to be [(from this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145886/change-time-locale-for-r/8147191#8147191):

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
```

For Unix-like systems the command appears to be (from the same question):

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the locale. For example:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US")
```

The locales available to you will depend on your system. See [the locales section of the R manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-admin.html#Locales) for some more information.