# Convert nasty time format from tera term

Tags: r, datetime

I got this time format

> Fri Aug 28 11:34:57,915 2020

from a tera term data logging. I'm trying to find a possibility to convert it to a more handy time format. So far, I couldn't find a proper package (e.g. `chron`, `lubridate` and `POSIXct`) or something similar. But so far, I never had such an issue by converting time formats so I hope others already know something.
Otherwise I have to re-arrange it somehow manually.

Comment: I know this is an old post, and  answered, but curious if you have access to the teraterm script to make edits there?  If so, you can make the call to _[gettime time_str <format string>](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/en/macro/command/gettime.html)_ with a custom format string argument  to produce a time-stamp in the format you prefer.  No post-processing necessary.

Comment: This is a question about how to use TeraTerm rather than a programming issue.  While you could of course write code to process the format, that would be a bizarre approach since you can configure the format in TeraTerm since v4.96 (2017), and even then the default is RFC 3339 format.  The format you have is the pre 4.96 default or has been explicitly set by `LogTimestampFormat` in the teraterm.ini file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```r
strptime("Fri Aug 28 11:34:57,915 2020", format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S")
#> [1] "2020-08-28 11:34:57 BST"
```

Or, if you want to ensure that you capture the year correctly, you will first need to get rid of the comma with the trailing milliseconds:

```r
f <- function(x) strptime(gsub(",\\d+", "", x), format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")

f(c("Fri Aug 28 11:34:57,915 2020", "Mon Feb 05 12:21:05,321 2018"))
#> [1] "2020-08-28 11:34:57 BST" "2018-02-05 12:21:05 GMT"
```

Comment: Upvote but to get rid of the comma doesn't mean to get rid of the decimals, use format string `%OS`. (And `sub(",", ".", x)`).

Comment: Sure, there was also strptime. When I execute your code above, I receive NA. That's weird as it is just one line which I do not modify at all..  do I have to load something, or so?

Comment: @Ben Is your locale an English language locale? Mine isn't so I have to `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")` and everything works.

Comment: @Ben the captures in `strptime` are locale dependent, so if your locale is set to somewhere that has different names for weekdays and months to the format you are parsing, you would need to change locale as per @RuiBarradas

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess this detail would have driven me insane through the day..  nevertheless, I have to figure out how it works. When I change it as given above from Rui, I receive: "Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored "

Comment: @RuiBarradas I think my regex finds any comma with trailing digits and removes both the comma and the trailing digits from the string?

Comment: Yes, that was my point. Don't remove the trailing digits, replace the comma with period and use format `"%OS"` to keep the decimals digits.

Comment: @Ben Are you on [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8147191/8245406)?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes :) I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r but so far, it doesn't work. Have to dive deeper..

Comment: great, found on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031002/get-weekdays-in-english-in-r the suggestion to use " Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English") " which finally worked while all other didn't. Now the strptime command also works! Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

If the format will always be the same, you can try to extract the necessary date elements using a regular expression (this is necessary to access the year information at the end) and then convert to the proper date format:

```
test <- "Fri Aug 28 11:34:57,915 2020"

test2 <- gsub(x = test, 
     pattern = "([A-Za-z]+) ([A-Za-z]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+),[0-9]+ ([0-9]+)",
     replacement = "\\2 \\3 \\7 \\4:\\5:\\6")

date <- as.POSIXct(test2, format = "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
date
```